# C# and adding integers

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty with the differences in syntax and the rules that follow with C# compared to Python.

so I have to create a program where the user is inputed how many eggs a chicken lays in a day, sums the total, and gives how many dozens.

here is my code that I have now

```
int c1 = Convert.ToInt32("How many eggs did chicken 1 lay?");
System.Console.ReadLine();
int c2 = Convert.ToInt32("How many eggs did chicken 2 lay?");
System.Console.ReadLine();
int c3 = Convert.ToInt32("How many eggs did chicken 3 lay?");
System.Console.ReadLine();
int c4 = Convert.ToInt32("How many eggs did chicken 3 lay?");

int Sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
int Total = (Sum / 12);
System.Console.WriteLine(Sum);
System.Console.WriteLine(Total);
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, provide example output and expected output.

Comment: `"How many eggs did chicken 1 lay?"` is not a number! You can't convert it directly.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error? If so, include it with your question.

Comment: This is nowhere near close to correct usage of these functions (and would also be incorrect in the direct "translation" to Python)

Comment: Hint: you probably want to use the value returned by `Console.ReadLine()`, and convert *that* using `Convert.ToInt32`. You probably want `Console.WriteLine` for the prompts.

Comment: Note that `int Total = (Sum / 12);` is prone to integer division cut-off problems.

Comment: @TaW to be fair, I think rounding errors are the least of the OPs worries.

Comment: @tim: Very true ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The message is only to show to the user so that he would know what he needs to enter. and it's not something that you may convert to integer. So you should just write it:

```
Console.Write("How many eggs did chicken 1 lay?");
```

You must cast the `string` you get from console `ReadLine` to `int`:

```
string sc1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
int c1 = int.Parse(sc1);
```

Comment: Without questions for chicken 2, 3 and 4, the program would be really confusing to the user.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek why would it be? I think i have fully described it for chicken 1 and he should actually be able to make it work for 4 of them. thats the reason I didn't use a loop, as I thought it might make the answer confusing

Comment: I agree it can be filled in, but in that case it is not complete code as you stated.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek The question clearly show that its for learning purposes and I think its enough to concentrate on the user's problem. other wise the answer would be considered as too board, just as questions can be.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - I will happily question chickens 2, 3, and 4, but I doubt they'd have much to talk about.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani the point is that the code you have provided, while generous, is confusing. You say *its enough to concentrate on the user's problem* - that problem is that the user does not understand how to capture console input. Simple as. An answer addressing anything other than this single point is going to confuse the user.

Comment: well I agree, I was hoping to answer his other questions ahead, but you are right. I just edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was able to get the completed project together

the final code looking as follows

```
        Console.Write("How many eggs did chicken 1 lay?");
        string sc1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int c1 = int.Parse(sc1);
        Console.Write("How many eggs did chicken 2 lay?");
        string sc2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int c2 = int.Parse(sc2);
        Console.Write("How many eggs did chicken 3 lay?");
        string sc3 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int c3 = int.Parse(sc3);
        Console.Write("How many eggs did chicken 3 lay?");
        string sc4 = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int c4 = int.Parse(sc4);


        int Sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
        int Total = (Sum / 12);

        System.Console.WriteLine("The sum of the eggs laid is  "  + Sum);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Dozen =  " +Total );

        System.Console.ReadLine();
```